# Formatting decimal point in crystal reports in required format

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have a number field in report which is having below type of values.

```
19707.51

9834.01
```

Now I need to format the above field to get the decimal place before 4 digits.

I tried giving this

```
mid(totext({Command_2.INVOICE_AMT},4),1,1)+'.'+ 
mid(totext({Command_2.INVOICE_AMT},4),2,length(totext({Command_2.INVOICE_AMT},4))-1)
```

Required output is

```
1.970.751,00

983.401,00
```

[image: I have this format in my system,how do i edit it?]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a formula which multiplies your values by 100.

Use the Format Editor for the formula. Choose an existing format or define your own if you need to.

[image]

Comment: What is the code that I should write inside thousand seperator?

Comment: Just seeing your values are „too small“. Create a formula, multiply your numbers by 100 and then format the formula.

Comment: Great. If your problem is solved please accept the answer.